# How to stop Exoplayer from a Recyclerview when closing an activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

In my app there is a recyclerview that with an exoplayer. When I leave my app or change the screen, the video keeps playing. I need to make it pause when I leave the screen.

I tried using the onViewRecycled method but the video is only paused when I return to the screen where the video is playing.

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    if (holder.simpleExoPlayer != null) {
        holder.positionExo = holder.simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        holder.simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }
}
```

My Adapter:

```
    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
                   //...
    holder.simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context);

                    // Bind the player to the view.
                    holder.videoCnt.setPlayer(holder.simpleExoPlayer);

                    holder.videoUri = Uri.parse(content.getVideo());

                    // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
                    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                            Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getString( R.string.app_name)));
                    // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
                    MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                            .createMediaSource(holder.videoUri);
                    // Prepare the player with the source.
                    holder.simpleExoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);

                   //...
}
```

How to pause the video correctly?

Comment: please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60134634/3904109